# How can I get columns for a specific table using jOOQ without pulling all table metadata into memory?

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I need to query a live MySQL database to check what columns a particular table has in a particular schema. The following code snippet is what I have now:

```java
List<Table<?>> tables = dslContext.meta().getTables();
Set<String> existingFields = null;
for (Table table: tables)
{
    if (table.getSchema().getName().equals(schema) && table.getName().equals(tableToCheck.getName()))
    {
        existingFields = Arrays.stream(table.fields()).map(Field::getName).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        break;
    }
}
```

This works, but it uses about a gigabyte of heap space when running against a DB instance with ~50,000 tables across all of its schema. Passing an argument to `getTables()` doesn't reduce the maximum memory footprint, it just reduces the number of elements returned. Passing an argument to `meta()` to filter at that level doesn't work for my use case because those versions of the method don't get live meta information [according to the documentation](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#meta(org.jooq.Schema...)). Is there a more efficient way to do this using jOOQ?

Answer (score 2):

As of writing, I haven't found a way of doing this with jOOQ, but the following code snippet  demonstrates how to get column names for a particular table in a particular schema using [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html):

```java
Set<String> existingFields = new HashSet<>();
ResultSet columns = connection.getMetaData().getColumns(null, schema, tableToCheck.getName(), null);
while(columns.next())
{
    existingFields.add(columns.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
}
```

This method uses only a few megabytes of heap space when querying the database instance mentioned in the question.